# Terminator Background image shades

Tags: terminator, jpeg

I use terminator and recently, I tried to add a background image to it through the option provided in preferences, and for some reason the image that it is rendering is a bit shady and the colors are a bit off. I have also attached the images to specify the same.

[image: The original image]

[image: This is the image from the terminator]

Comment: Have you enabled transparency?

Comment: @muru Thanks!! I set it to zero now its working fine!!

Comment: No problem. Can you post that as an answer, with a screenshot or two? I don't have terminator on hand to do it myself.

Comment: Yes, I will post it.